# Must the first view must always be called index.aspx?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-views

I have created a controller called loginController.cs and i have created a view called login.aspx

How do I call that view from loginController.cs?

The `ActionResult` is always set to index and for neatness, I want to specify what view the controller uses when called rather than it always calling its default index?

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: I had this long-winded answer lined up for you.. but I think I might just ask: Why do you want to change the default behaviour?

Comment: It doesn't have to be called index.aspx, aspx should not even be in the url. It's all about routing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can customize pretty much everything in MVC routing - there is no particular restriction on how routes look like (only ordering is important), you can name actions differently from method names (via ActionName attribute), your can name views whatever you want (i.e. by returning particular view by name).

```
return View("login");
```

Answer (score 2):

In the interest of actually answering the question.. you can add a route **ABOVE** your default route in `Global.asax`:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "SpecialLoginRoute",
    "login/",
    new { controller = "Login", action = "Login", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    "Default", // Route name
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
);
```

..although, without properly thinking through what you're trying to achieve (that being.. changing what MVC does by default) you're bound to end up with lots and lots of messy routes.

Comment: Well... here's a better question > Do all views have to have a folder to be called by an ActionResult? I have a contact folder which will have add, edit, delete views. I only want one controller "contact" for that. this means that i have to name one of the add, edit or delete views "index". Which could be confusing later on.

Comment: It's also confusing to see at the top index.aspx when in fact i'm looking at the login page or edit page. see my prob?

Comment: "index.aspx" shouldn't be in the URL unless you're manually putting it there. You don't have to put the filename in the URL. E.g: website.com/Login/Index/Index.aspx.. you just put website.com/Login.

Comment: Yea, i've got that. the last comment is a red herring, I meant when i'm developing the pages... at the top i see index.aspx and i'm thinking.. which one is that? Oh right it's the add contact page. hehe. So I was thinking, I'll rename it add.aspx and then redirect the controller to use add.aspx as the construct view. but if it's as dirty as the routes.MapRoute. I may just put up with it.

Answer (score 1):

Your return the view from your controller via your Action methods.

```
public class LoginController:Controller
{
  public ActionResult Index()
  {
    return View();
    //this method will return `~/Views/Login/Index.csthml/aspx` file
  }
  public ActionResult RecoverPassword()
  {
    return View();
    //this method will return `~/Views/Login/RecoverPassword.csthml/aspx` file
  }
}
```

If you need to return a different view (other than the action method name, you can explicitly mention it

```
  public ActionResult FakeLogin()
  {
    return View("Login");
    //this method will return `~/Views/Login/Login.csthml/aspx` file
  }
```

If you want to return a view which exist in another controller folder, in ~/Views, you can use the full path

```
   public ActionResult FakeLogin2()
  {
    return View("~/Views/Account/Signin");
    //this method will return `~/Views/Account/Signin.csthml/aspx` file
  }
```

Comment: return View("~/Views/homepage") does not seem to return the homepage.aspx even though it exists within the View root. any ideas?

Comment: [InvalidOperationException: The view '~/Views/index' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched:
~/Views/index]

Comment: You missed the controller name. The format is ~/Views/{ControllerName}/{ActionMethodName}.aspx ex : ~/views/home/index.aspx

Comment: Right. I'll think about that and try when I get home. PHP by day, .NET by night. hehe... Thanks a bunch!